# wordpress pagination links problems

Tags: pagination, wordpress

I'm trying to implement pagination in a custom WP-Query. The pagination is done correctly, but the links are wrong. If I have, for example, 10 posts and 8 posts per page, I have a page 1 with 8 posts (OK for now), a page 2 with 2 posts (still OK), but I can access a page 3 with 0 posts, and so on...

I'm trying also to implement wp_navi an I'm having an infinite navigation menu for only 10 posts.

The code used is the following:

```
<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Next') ?>
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;   
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query("category_name=Destacadas&paged=".get_query_var('paged'));        
while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post_container">
    <?php include ('post-info-reduced.php'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Have you had this problem?

Comment: how is wordpress going to know how many pages there is, before you even run the query? i guess you need to check if you are at the last page yourself

Comment: Sounds logic, but I haven't found any post on any page on this topic

Comment: $nextPagesPosts = new WP_Query("category_name=Destacadas&paged=".(get_query_var('paged')+1); if($nextPagesPosts->have_posts()) next_posts_link

Comment: It's an useful workaround, but how could this work with wp_pagenavi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for using it with WP-PageNavi:

http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html